# Simple computational number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

my question is 'contained' within a very simple problem that I intuitively know how to do, but don't know how to express mathematically.

I am writing a program that will find the perfect numbers in a given range.

n(2 $\leq$ n $\leq$ 500)

For each $n$ determine the proper divisors $d_{1}$, $d_{2}$, ..., $d_{r}$

Print $n$ when $\sum_{i=1}^r d_{i} = n $

That's all fine - I understand it. Whilst trying to translate this into Python is when I realised I have a problem.

It is *obvious* that the proper divisors of 6 are 1, 2, and 3. Likewise it is easy to work them out for many other numbers, but I don't have a clue how to express that process mathematically.

So basically my question is this; How do you construct a function for factorising a number?

Comment: There are fancy algorithms, but for $2$ to $500$ you don't need fancy. For all $x$ from $1$ to $n-1$, check whether $x$ divides $n$. Keep a running total. You don't need to go to $n-1$, you can go to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Comment: If you need prime numbers for a lot of programs, it is handy to have a file.  The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is easy to program.  In Python it quickly made me a file of all the primes up to 10 million.

Comment: I suggest to check for divisors only up to $\sqrt n$, and then divide $n$ by every divisor found to get the other half of divisors. (That's how I once programmed it on a calculator.)

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions - I have it sorted now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For numbers up to $500$, [trial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) will work fine.

Let's start with an input number $n \geq 2$ and trial divisor $d=2$.

- We check if $d$ divides $n$.

  - If $d$ does not divide $n$, then replace $d$ with $d+1$, and continue.
  - If it does, we have discovered the divisor $d$ (we may print it to the screen, store it in an array, etc.).  We replace $n$ with $n/d$.  If $n=1$, then we have fully factored it, so we may break.  Otherwise, we continue (do not increment $d$ here).

Note that at most $500$ trial divisions will actually be performed.

Note that this algorithm will always produce a prime factorisation: if $d$ is composite, then $d$ is divisible by a prime $p<d$, but this prime would have been factored out of $n$ at an earlier step.

We can improve the performance of this algorithm (i.e., perform fewer trial divisions) by only checking divisibility by $d \in \{2,3\} \cup \{k \geq 5: k \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6\}$, since all primes are in this set.

Most programming languages have an inbuilt mod function, so we can easily check if $n \equiv 0 \pmod d$, e.g., in C we check `if(n%d==0) { ... }`.